# Is there a plumbing command to create tag object?

Tags: git

For every object type there is a related plumbing command: for `commit object`s there is `commit-tree`, for `blob object`s `hash-object` and for `tree object`s `write-tree`.

Is there a plumbing command which allows to just insert the `tag object` inside the `Object Database` without creating a file in the `refs/tags` dicrectory, id est without using `git tag`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [`git mktag`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mktag.html), which is pretty primitive.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a plumbing command which allows to just insert the tag object inside the Object Database without creating a file in the refs/tags directory?

No.

To add to [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39685897/6309), [`git mktag`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mktag) was introduced in Git v0.99, Apr. 2005, [commit ec4465a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec4465adb38d21966acdc9510ff15c0fe4539468):

> Reads a tag contents from its standard input and creates a tag object.
> The input must be a well formed tag object.

> three lines of "object `<sha1>`" + "type `<typename>`" + "tag `<tagname>`", followed by some free-form signature that git itself doesn't care about, but that can be verified with gpg or similar.

It did not insert anything in the Object database though. It ([`mktag.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0fad0fdd4beadb2ff06af8d5a16d509cd8796ee4/mktag.c)) was used by [`git tag script` at the time](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0fad0fdd4beadb2ff06af8d5a16d509cd8796ee4/git-tag-script):

```
object=$(git-mktag < .tmp-tag)
mkdir -p "$GIT_DIR/refs/tags"
echo $object > "$GIT_DIR/refs/tags/$name"
```

The fourth line for `mktag` was introduced in Git 1.4.2-rc3, Apr. 2006, [commit 446c6fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/446c6faec69f7ac521b8b9fc2b1874731729032f).
Creating a valid tag is there shown as:

```
git-mktag <tag.sig >.git/refs/tags/mytag
```

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), "[`git mktag`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c7d6d419b0ddbc895aaf5de81a79a10773842d89/Documentation/git-mktag.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mktag))</sup> validates its input using its own rules before writing a tag object---it has been updated to share the logic with `git fsck`".

See [commit 06ce791](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06ce79152be8dab44b63faf4486d5c5c171434af) (06 Jan 2021), [commit 2aa9425](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2aa9425fbeb58f459240f223525e512499ab62e4), [commit 3f390a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f390a366cc4a083b11452b899a04416aea00bdd), [commit 9a1a3a4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a1a3a4d4c5648b94dbe8f34b83271d96dbaa6ec), [commit acfc013](https://github.com/git/git/commit/acfc01332bc477e19b8af6b5002c0b962fde3326), [commit 1f3299f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f3299fda9d0800d8e882540d36e4d78797e998e), [commit acf9de4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/acf9de4c94e0de260f962dc04cc4f9007cedbf1a), [commit 40ef015](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40ef015a2711ef603ab712e0a6882e24e980ef6d), [commit dfe3948](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfe39487284af223737c58dd830261c2995f4fba), [commit 0c43911](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c439117bbc8f51b9c13b323ea7a9f76892a433d), [commit 692654d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/692654dca01dda9951a81de4ecfa958b61b8bc5c), [commit 30f882c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30f882c16d64e9859d823db16ae7c5157f09397b), [commit ca9a1ed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca9a1ed969f09c8b6efc3e1d925ac1bda7370886), [commit 47c95e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47c95e77d158e4660dab25b9fdd6f4d70013b430), [commit 3b9e4dd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b9e4dd3a3be6d39bece6a9272640be3b5a817d2), [commit 5c2303e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c2303e0c7a981528dae68d4979d3bfdc2526276), [commit 317c176](https://github.com/git/git/commit/317c1762798f9e1ee0cb8096a2071561a8bb1fdc), [commit 0d35ccb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d35ccb5e07662ed95775ed2e59eec4026f67931), [commit b5ca549](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5ca549c932a2818869dba7cc7c60a8ec5946a8d), [commit aba5377](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aba5377f693df650879a23ae549ca458ff116965), [commit 18430ed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18430ed363f469d5fe6e143857b7fe72aca807ba) (05 Jan 2021), and [commit 9ce0fc3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ce0fc33118892a22841f474ed239b512346c83a), [commit f59b61d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f59b61dc4d0bb4e5e3bc8c48894ad346ece8cdbe) (23 Dec 2020) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c7d6d41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7d6d419b0ddbc895aaf5de81a79a10773842d89), 25 Jan 2021)</sup>

First, its documentation changes:

> ### [`mktag doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18430ed363f469d5fe6e143857b7fe72aca807ba): update to explain why to use this
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Change the `mktag` documentation to compare itself to the similar "`hash-object -t tag`" command.
> Before this someone reading the documentation wouldn't have much of an idea what the difference was.
>
> Let's allude to our own validation logic, and cross-link the "`mktag`" and "`hash-object`" documentation to aid discover-ability.
> A follow-up change to migrate "`mktag`" to use "`fsck`" validation will make the part about validation logic clearer.

`git mktag` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/18430ed363f469d5fe6e143857b7fe72aca807ba/Documentation/git-mktag.txt#L6):

> ### git-mktag - Creates a tag object with extra validation

`git mktag` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/18430ed363f469d5fe6e143857b7fe72aca807ba/Documentation/git-mktag.txt#L17-L28):

> Reads a tag contents on standard input and creates a tag object.
> The output is the new tag's `<object>` identifier.
>
> This command is mostly equivalent to [`git hash-object`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object)
> invoked with `-t tag -w --stdin`. I.e. both of these will create and
> write a tag found in `my-tag`:
>
> ```sh
> git mktag <my-tag
> git hash-object -t tag -w --stdin <my-tag
> ```
>
> The difference is that mktag will die before writing the tag if the
> tag doesn't pass a sanity check.

Then, it illustrates how the tag signature file format has changed over the years:

> ### [`mktag`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a1a3a4d4c5648b94dbe8f34b83271d96dbaa6ec): allow omitting the header/body \n separator
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Change mktag's acceptance rules to accept an empty body without an empty line after the header again.
> This fixes an ancient unintended regression in "`mktag`".
>
> When "`mktag`" was introduced in [ec4465a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec4465adb38d21966acdc9510ff15c0fe4539468) (Add "tag" objects that can be used to sign other objects., 2005-04-25, Git v0.99) the input checks were much looser.
> When it was documented it [6cfec03](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6cfec0368038ec4c564798701e95a84658e6b705) ("`mktag`: minimally update the description.", 2007-06-10, Git v1.5.3-rc0) it was clearly intended for this `\n` to be optional:
>
> ```
> The message, when [it] exists, is separated by a blank line from
> the header.
> ```
>
> But then in [e0aaf78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0aaf781f656671694a0aa04d8a665bd4d7956e6) ("`mktag.c`: improve verification of tagger field and tests", 2008-03-27, Git v1.5.5-rc3 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5fbd0a44cfee7be96fe29b9252f34b8f1bce9ac5)) this was made an error, seemingly by accident.
> It was just a result of the general header checks, and all the tests after that patch have a trailing empty line (but did not before).
>
> Let's allow this again, and tweak the test semantics changed in [e0aaf78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0aaf781f656671694a0aa04d8a665bd4d7956e6) to remove the redundant empty line.
> New tests added in previous commits of mine already added an explicit test for allowing the empty line between header and body.

---

Most importantly: `mktag` uses fsck now:

> ### [`mktag`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/acf9de4c94e0de260f962dc04cc4f9007cedbf1a): use `fsck` instead of custom `verify_tag()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Change the validation logic in "`mktag`" to use `fsck`'s `fsck_tag()` instead of its own custom parser.
> Curiously the logic for both dates back to the same commit ([ec4465a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec4465adb38d21966acdc9510ff15c0fe4539468) (Add "tag" objects that can be used to sign other objects, 2005-04-25, Git v0.99)).
> Let's unify them so we're not maintaining two sets functions to verify that a tag is OK.
>
> The behavior of `fsck_tag()` and the old "`mktag`" code being removed here is different in few aspects.
>
> I think it makes sense to remove some of those checks, namely:
>
> A.  `fsck` only cares that the timezone matches `[-+][0-9]{4}`.
> The `mktag` code disallowed values larger than 1400.
> Yes there's currently no timezone [with a greater offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets), but
> since we allow any number of non-offical timezones (e.g. +1234)
> passing this through seems fine. Git also won't break in the
> future if e.g. French Polynesia decides it needs to outdo the Line
> Islands when it comes to timezone extravagance.
>
> B. `fsck` allows missing author names such as "`tagger <email>`", `mktag` wouldn't, but would allow e.g. "`tagger [2 spaces] <email>`" (but not "`tagger [1 space] <email>`").
> Now we allow all of these.
>
> C. Like B, but "`mktag`" disallowed spaces in the `<email>` part, `fsck` allows it.
> In some ways `fsck_tag()` is stricter than "`mktag`" was, namely:
>
> D. `fsck` disallows zero-padded dates, but `mktag` didn't care.
> So e.g. the timestamp "`0000000000 +0000`" produces an error now.
> A test in "t1006-cat-file.sh" relied on this, it's been changed to use "hash-object" (without `fsck`) instead.
> There was one check I deemed worth keeping by porting it over to `fsck_tag()`:
>
> E. "`mktag`" did not allow any custom headers, and by extension (as an empty commit is allowed) also forbade an extra stray trailing newline after the headers it knew about.
> Add a new check in the "ignore" category to `fsck` and use it. This
> somewhat abuses the facility added in efaba7cc77f (fsck:
> optionally ignore specific fsck issues completely, 2015-06-22).
> This is somewhat of hack, but probably the least invasive change
> we can make here. The fsck command will shuffle these categories
> around, e.g. under `--strict` the "`info`" becomes a "`warn`" and "`warn`"
> becomes "`error`". Existing users of fsck's (and others,
> e.g. index-pack) `--strict` option rely on this.
>
> So we need to put something into a category that'll be ignored by
> all existing users of the API. Pretending that
> `fsck.extraHeaderEntry=error` ("`ignore`" by default) was set serves
> to do this for us.

`git mktag` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/acf9de4c94e0de260f962dc04cc4f9007cedbf1a/Documentation/git-mktag.txt#L28-L35):

> tag doesn't pass a [`git fsck`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) check.
>
> The "`fsck`" check done `mktag` is stricter than what [`git fsck`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck)
> would run by default in that all `fsck.<msg-id>` messages are promoted
> from warnings to errors (so e.g. a missing "tagger" line is an error).
>
> Extra headers in the object are also an error under `mktag`, but ignored
> by [`git fsck`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck)